# Copying data between 2 different hadoop clusters

Tags: hadoop, distcp

I am trying to copy data from one HDFS directory to another using distcp:

Source hadoop version:
hadoop version
Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.3.1

Destination hadoop version:
hadoop version
Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.4.0

Command I am using is:

```
hadoop distcp hftp://foo.test.net:50070/new_data/raw/new_logs/utc_date=2014-09-01/utc_hour=22 hdfs://localhost.localdomain/user/cloudera/new_logs
```

Error message I am getting is:

```
java.io.IOException: Copied: 0 Skipped: 0 Failed: 13
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.close(DistCp.java:582)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

==

Logs from "Task Logs":

```
2014-09-02 13:50:30,947 INFO org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp: FAIL utc_hour=22/000012_0 :     java.io.IOException: HTTP_OK expected, received 500
at     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.HftpFileSystem$RangeHeaderUrlOpener.connect(HftpFileSystem.java:376)
at     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.ByteRangeInputStream.openInputStream(ByteRangeInputStream.java:119)
at     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.ByteRangeInputStream.getInputStream(ByteRangeInputStream.java:103)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.ByteRangeInputStream.read(ByteRangeInputStream.java:187)
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:83)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.copy(DistCp.java:424)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.map(DistCp.java:547)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.map(DistCp.java:314)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)

2014-09-02 13:50:31,118 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater: Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
2014-09-02 13:50:31,131 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:cloudera (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Copied: 0     Skipped: 0 Failed: 13
2014-09-02 13:50:31,131 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child
java.io.IOException: Copied: 0 Skipped: 0 Failed: 13
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.close(DistCp.java:582)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
2014-09-02 13:50:31,145 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Runnning cleanup for the task
```

=

Any help?

Thanks,

Rio

Comment: Hi, is my syntax correct based on the hadoop version I am using?

Comment: All I need is a way to transfer data between 2 different hadoop clusters on different servers.

Comment: Updated with Task logs

Comment: Try HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs hadoop distcp <hftp> <hdfs>

Comment: IME distcp error msgs are about as helpful as "oops somfin didn't work mate!", check permissions, paths, firewalls, hostnames, etc etc

Comment: @pensz can you elaborate a little bit more? Thanks

Comment: I mean you can try `HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs hadoop distcp hftp://foo.test.net/new_data/raw/new_logs/utc_date=2014-09-01/utc_hour=22 hdfs://localhost.localdomain/user/cloudera/new_logs`

1. use `hadoop dfs -ls` to make sure that you can read source hadoop cluster. 50070 is default datanode port, not namenode port;
2. make sure you have permission to write destination hadoop cluster. hdfs user is the super user in CDH, so I add HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs.